# Знаки препинания в заглавии текста

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста расставить знаки препинания в заглавии сочинения. Звучит оно так:

> Культура речи в сети Интернет - что это, и какое влияние имеет общение
> в Интернете?

Answer (score 1):

Если принять схему заглавия с темой и подтемой приемлемой, можно получить, отбросив лишние знаки, такой заголовок:

«*Культура речи в сети Интернет: что это и какое влияние имеет общение в Интернете*».

Поскольку Интернет есть (всемирная) компьютерная система **сетей**, хорошо бы избавиться от повтора:

«*Культура речи в Интернете: что это и какое влияние имеет общение в компьютерной сети*».

Остаётся вопрос о *влиянии*: чего и  на что? Предложил бы такую редакцию:

*«Что это — культура речи в в соцсетях? Каково её влияние на общение в Интернете?»*.

Comment: Маленькая, но важная коррекция: между двумя вопросительными предложениями запятая не ставится

Comment: @виктор1799 Не в этом случае. Нет однородности.

Comment: Причем здесь однородность? Розенталь четко пишет: "Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится между двумя вопросительными предложениями:  Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?"

Comment: @виктор1799 При том, что оно звучит не по-русски здесь. Надо понимать, почему существует это правило и на чём оно основано, а не слепо следовать ему. А основано оно на логических ударениях. Присоединение вопроса тоже может иметь место.